# How to use an ISpecimenBuilder / ICustomization based on another value

Tags: c#, autofixture

I started using AutoFixture for building my test suite, and I'm pretty convinced that this is what I should be using
to make my tests clear, however, there are a couple of things which I simply don't know how to implement this.

First, let me try you to explain the concept.

I do have class which represents a "Company" entity.

```
public sealed class Compnay
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime FoundingDate { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

And I do have a class of "Person" entities, which represents the persons which are working in a specific company.

```
public sealed class Person
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfMarriage { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I do have an interface to abstract away the current Date/Time.

```
public interface IDateTimeProvider
{
    DateTime Now { get; }
}
```

And I have a function that queries the companies where there are persons working that are born in the current year.

```
IEnumerable<Company> Get()
{
    return this.DB.Companies.Include(x => x.Persons)
               .Where(x => x.DateOfBirth.Year == this.dateTimeProvider.Now)
               .Select(x => new {
                   // ... Implementation ...
               });
}
```

Now, in my unit test, I would like to verify that the entities which are returned are correct.
So I need AutoFixture to generate a random date (because I need to have random dates, so ensure that my code does work
with different Date/Time(s)).

But the problem is that the rest of my test needs to have access to this date because, in order to built my assertion, I
need to calculate which persons are going to be returned (which is dependent) on the current Date/Time.

One option would be to freeze the Date/Time(s) which are created by AutoFixture, but than suddenly, all Date/Times, even the founding date of a company would be this date, which is something which I don't want, since my query might be dependent on that also.

How can I tackle this problem?

Might be important to know that I'm using the "AutoData" attribute to avoid having Fixture configuration inside my tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of injecting the `IDateTimeProvider` in your repository, you should instead pass the filtering arguments as parameters into your `Get()` method. This way you could just pick a date out of the entities generated by AutoFixture and you don't need to freeze values at all.

```cs
/* repository */
public IEnumerable<Company> Get(DateTime foundingDate)
{
    return this.context.Companies.Include(x => x.Persons)
            .Where(x => x.FoundingDate == foundingDate)
            .Select(x => x);
}

/* test method */
[Theory, PersistenceData]
public void Foo(
    List<Company> companies, [Frozen]MyContext context,
    CompaniesRepository repository)
{
    context.Companies.AddRange(companies);
    context.SaveChanges();

    var actual = repository.Get(companies[2].FoundingDate);

    Assert.Equal(new[] { companies[2] }, actual);
}
```

In this example I am using `PersistenceData` that is a auto data attribute created with [EntityFrameworkCore.AutoFixture](https://github.com/aivascu/EntityFrameworkCore.AutoFixture).